# CakePHP validation error doesn't show up on file upload field

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a file upload field in CakePHP which allows images to be uploaded.

All is fine. All I need to do is validate the field. I am using the solution from *[CakePHP – Uploaded File Validation in Models](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2008/06/cakephp-uploaded-file-validation-in-models/)*:

The function is working and returning the appropriate error. I am using the following code to generate the file upload field.

```
echo $form->label('Game Thumbnail');
echo $form->file('Game.game_thumbnail_url');
```

and following code to add the validation in the model

```
'game_thumbnail_url' => array(
    'valid_upload' => array (
      'rule' => array('validateUploadedFile', false),
       'message' => 'Please select a valid game thumbnail',
       'allowEmpty' => false
  )
),
```

But the error message doesn't show up, it works fine for other fields but not for this one.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not using `FormHelper::input`, which outputs the field, label *and error*, you need to manually output the error as well using `$form->error('Game.game_thumbnail_url')`.